# ¿Cómo Ejecutar dos o mas tareas en paralelo (al mismo tiempo) en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy procesando imágenes en flutter, cada procesamiento se realiza en un isolate, para no bloquear el isolate principal.

Hace un par de semanas me encuentro investigando dos puntos que necesito realizar:

1. Pero necesito lanzar (ejecutar) dos tareas (procesamientos) al mismo tiempo para reducir el tiempo de respuesta, ya que hasta ahora solo he logrado ejecutar una tarea y luego cuando termina, ejecuta la siguiente, es decir, utilizo isolates pero siguo ejecutando código secuencial.
2. También necesito ejecutar una tarea (procesamiento) y continuar ejecutando el resto de código sin esperar a que retorne respuesta, pues el procesamiento demora unos minutos, pero sí deseo saber cuando termina de procesar, es decir saber cuándo finalizó esa tarea, para poder obtener su resultado.

He intentado hacer esto quitando el await al ejecutar las funciones asíncronas y también probe los Stream, pero siempre esperan a que retorne la respuesta de la función (tarea), y no continúan ejecutando el resto de código, es decir va línea a línea ejecutando, soy nuevo usando Flutter así que es posible que me este perdiendo de algo, agradecería sus colaboraciones.

IDEA PARTE 1:

```
void main(List<String> args) async{
  
  print("Inicio");    

  // ejecutar al mismo tiempo
  tarea1([]);  
  tarea2([]);  

  // esperar sus respuestas

  // resto de código
  // ...
  // ...

  print("fin"); 
}

Future<Map<String,dynamic>> tarea1(List<dynamic> input) async {
  // crea un isolate 
  return {};
}

Future<Map<String,dynamic>> tarea2(List<dynamic> input) async {
  // crea un isolate 
  return {};
}
```

IDEA PARTE 2:

```
void main(List<String> args) async{
  
  
  print("Inicio");

  Tarea tarea = Tarea();

  var resultado = await tarea.tarea1([]);   // espera el resultado
  tarea.tarea2([]);  // no espera el resultado

  // continua ejecutando el resto de código
  // resto de código
  // ...
  // ...

  print("fin"); 
}



class Tarea{

  // variable que almacena el resultado 
  // de la tarea 2 cuando finalice
  Map<String,dynamic> resultado2 = {};

  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> tarea1(List<dynamic> input) async {
  // crea un isolate 
  return {};
  }

  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> tarea2(List<dynamic> input) async {
  // crea un isolate 
  return {};
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la colaboración de carlitos98081212121 y después de intentar varias formas de código, por fin e llegado a una solución para el punto número 1 de mi pregunta.

Comparto la solución que funciona hasta el momento:

```
final futures = [
      compute(tarea1, 200),
      compute(tarea2, 100),
    ];
 final results = await Future.wait(futures);
```

Los argumentos 200 y 100 sólo son los parámetros que reciben cada función.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar el siguiente codigo

```
final resp = await Future.wait([
   tarea1,
   tarea2,
])
```

con esto obtienes un arreglo con ambas respuesta de forma simultaneas

Comment: Hola carlitos98081212121, gracias por tu colaboración, las respuesta que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.